# Finding and Grouping like children

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, search-trees

I'm working on a dependency managemen solution for a JavaScript.  I'm trying to find the best pattern for grouping similar items in a graph into their own 'modules'.

Given a dependency tree like shown below, I have a 'main' module ( app ), that has 5 children ( login, dashboard, form, builder, users ).  These children might share some common deps amongst them.

[image]

I'd like to create a function that would find the commons and group them upwards or in some cases where the overlap would out weight the benefit, creating a new module between them.

In a perfect world, would create a graph like this.  Obviously given a big enough tree, it could over-optimize creating too many child trees so probably stopping at level-3 would be ideal.

[image]

In this example:

- `d1` was shared 90% of the time, lets move it into the main module.
- `d6` was used in 3 of the 5 modules, lets create a separate module for that combo.  - `d5` was used in 2 of the 5 modules, lets create a separate module for that combination.
- `d3` was used in 2 of the 5 modules, lets create a separate module for that combo.

Comment: This smells somewhat like [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: 1. Can you define "find the commons" more precisely?  What exactly is a common?  Is it a module that appears in at least one or more of the dependencies (i.e., transitively depends on App)?  Is it that it transitively depends on two or more of the children of App (i.e., two or more modules that depend on App)?  2. Are you able to specify what objective function you want to maximize?  As it stands this does not look like a well-posed problem, since you have a multi-objective optimization problem and no description how to trade off between the multiple objectives.